# XSL:Number count not working as expected -- Issue with my XPath?

Tags: xslt, xpath, count

Here's the XML

```
<row>
    <cell>blah blah</cell>

    <check>
        <option/>
        <option/>
        <option/>
        <option/>
        <option/>
        <option/>
    </check>
</row>
```

Here is the XSL

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="inputLevel">
        <xsl:number count="option" level="any" from="."/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$inputLevel"/>
</xsl:template>
```

All I get is "0". http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp says "." means the current node. Shouldn't it be returning "6"?

Edit1: I wanted to look for option tags at ANY level, not just check. Should have explained but the option tags could exist at any level below

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation of your problem and for a complete, short and easy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to count descendant `option`s you shouldn't use `xsl:number` but:

```
<xsl:variable name="inputLevel" select="count(.//option)">
```

Comment: This was the solution. Man I love SO! <3

Comment: I tried to mark it was the answer, but SO said "Wait 5 minutes" and I forgot to come back. :P But it's marked now. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the xpath expression `option` won't match anything at the `row` element - try this instead:

```
<xsl:number count="check/option" level="any" from="." />
```

To look for `option` elements at any level use the following syntax:

```
<xsl:number count="//option" level="any" from="." />
```

I don't think the `from` attribute is reqired, and the `level` attribute probably isn't doing what you think it is (I'm also not sure what it does...)

Comment: I wanted to look for option tags at ANY level, not just check. Should have explained but the option tags could exist at any level below <row>

Comment: Actually, the count attribute of xsl:number is a pattern, not an XPath expression, and using //option won't make any difference because as a pattern, "option" and "//option" match exactly the same nodes. No: to find the answer, just read the spec for xsl:number. You're imagining it does something completely different from what it actually does.

Answer (score 2):

From the **[XSLT 1.0 W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#number)**:

> **"If no `value` attribute is specified, then the `xsl:number
>   element` inserts a number based on the
>   position of the current node in the
>   source tree.** The following
>   attributes control how the current
>   node is to be numbered:
>
> The `level`attribute specifies what
>   levels of the source tree should be
>   considered; it has the values
>   `single`, `multiple` or `any`. The
>   default is `single`.
>
> The `count` attribute is a pattern
>   that specifies what nodes should be
>   counted at those levels. If count
>   attribute is not specified, then it
>   defaults to the pattern that matches
>   any node with the same node type as
>   the current node and, if the current
>   node has an expanded-name, with the
>   same expanded-name as the current node
>
> When `level="any"`, it constructs a
>   list of length one containing the
>   number of nodes that match the `count`
>   pattern and belong to the set
>   containing the current node and all
>   nodes at any level of the document
>   that are before the current node in
>   document order, excluding any
>   namespace and attribute nodes (in
>   other words **the union of the members
>   of the preceding and ancestor-or-self
>   axes**). If the `from` attribute is
>   specified, then only nodes after the
>   first node before the current node
>   that match the from pattern are
>   considered. ".

**From this text it is clear that only nodes that are ancestors or are preceding the current node are counted**.

In this question, the current node is the top element node `row` and it has 0 ancestor and 0 preceding element nodes.

Therefore, the returned result is correct!

**Solution**:

Use:

```
count(descendant::option)
```

The result of evaluating this expression is the count of all `option` elements in the document, that are descendents of the current node (the `row` element).

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks. Could you, please reply to the email that I sent?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't check that direction early. For better there is a query over the data dump at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/99534/