# XSL id() function inside xsl:number count

Tags: xslt

While converting XML to HTML, I'm trying to output the xref element as a link with an auto-generated chapter number that's pulled from the chapter element the xref refers to.

For example, with an XML source file like this:

```
<chapter id="a_chapter">
  <title>Title</title>
  <para>...as seen in <xref linkend="some_other_chapter">.</para>
</chapter>

<chapter id="some_other_chapter">
  <title>Title</title>
  <para>Some text here.</para>
</chapter>
```

where there are two chapters and the xref refers to the second chapter, the xref in the generated HTML should output like this:

```
<section id="a_chapter">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>...as seen in <a href="#some_other_chapter">Chapter 2</a>.</p>
</section>
```

But I'm not sure how to count the chapter element that the xref @linkend refers to. I tried using xsl:number, but I'm unable to use the id() function within the count:

```
<xsl:template match="xref">

  <xsl:variable name="label">
    <xsl:when test="id(@linkend)[self::chapter]"><xsl:text>Chapter </xsl:text></xsl:when>
  </xsl:variable

  <xsl:variable name="count">
    <xsl:if test="id(@linkend)[self::chapter]"><xsl:number count="id(@linkend)/chapter" level="any" format="1"/></xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>

  <a href="#{@linkend}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$label"/><xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

I also tried using just "chapter" as the value of the xsl:number count, but that produced "Chapter 0" for all of the outputs.

Am I way off here, or just making a stupid xpath mistake? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are using `count` wrongly. Please goolge proper solution, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877193/xslnumber-count-not-working-as-expected-issue-with-my-xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, change your context before invoking `<xsl:number>`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="id(@linkend)">
  <xsl:number/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In XSLT 2.0, change your context with the `select=` attribute:

```
<xsl:number select="id(@linkend)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I'm using XSLT 1.0, and the for-each solution worked for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What might be the easiest route would be to use a moded template for `chapter` to produce the label.

Small example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <chapter id="a_chapter">
        <title>Title</title>
        <para>...as seen in <xref linkend="some_other_chapter"/>.</para>
    </chapter>

    <chapter id="some_other_chapter">
        <title>Title</title>
        <para>Some text here.</para>
    </chapter>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xref">
        <a href="#{@linkend}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/chapter[@id=current()/@linkend]" mode="label"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chapter" mode="label">
        <xsl:text>Chapter </xsl:text>
        <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <chapter id="a_chapter">
      <title>Title</title>
      <para>...as seen in <a href="#some_other_chapter">Chapter 2</a>.</para>
   </chapter>
   <chapter id="some_other_chapter">
      <title>Title</title>
      <para>Some text here.</para>
   </chapter>
</doc>
```